# What should I do to prevent multiple request for same item to amazon S3? Browser Caching ? Something else?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, offline-caching

I am working on an online chat application and I need some help. I want to send and receive media and I thought of using **Amazon S3** for this. Now the problem arises when suppose person A sends an image to B and B clicks on it and the request goes to the server and server requests S3 to return image and it is shown in browser but when person B clicks back and wants to see it again, the process will be repeated again... (for all request for same image)

1. What is the best practice for this type of application, and should it be good to use S3, or should I go on with some other way?
2. If this way is correct, how do I prevent multiple requests, Is there a way to cache images in the browser or so? Or any other approach to this will help.
3. Or should I make objects public and store the requested images' URL in localstorage or so?

What is the best approach for this??

PS: I'm using node.js for backend.

Comment: It looks good to me. Images will be automatically cached in the browser if `Cache-Control` header is set properly.

Comment: Why do you want to prevent multiple requests, given that they are different users requesting the data? What problem/issue are you trying to resolve (eg cost, performance, features)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein For the sake of preventing load on server when **same person** is requesting for a resource repeatedly, my application is requesting server(in turn S3) for each of those request. I want to prevent repeated request for same object by same user

Comment: If the request is going to Amazon S3, it is not causing a load on your server. It would, however, cause additional Data Transfer costs. That's why I'm asking what is your priority... is it to save costs, improve performance, etc? Is there a specific thing that is currently 'bad'? Caching in the user's browser will reduce repeated requests, but will come at the cost of providing the most recent information (eg for an updated object). Thus, it's a trade-off between caching and giving the most-recent content. As per @jellycsc above, this can be configured for the browser.

Comment: There's nothing currently going 'bad' but I wanted to know whether there exists a better way of doing it (or whether my approach is correct)